# htaccess: redirect both www and non-www to a subdomain

Tags: php, .htaccess

No, I do NOT want to redirect a non-www domain to a www domain ... what I need to be able to to is ensure that a 302 redirect is applied to my domain in both cases:

```
mydomain.com
www.mydomain.com

302 to sub.mydomain.com
```

Perhaps I need to do the non-www redirection first before the 302 rule, but either way... i just need to make sure that anyone trying to visit my domain is redirected to one of my subdomains.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This will redirect any requests that go to either `mydomain.com` or `www.mydomain.com` to `sub.mydomain.com`:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^mydomain.com$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.mydomain.com$ 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://sub.mydomain.com/ [R=302,L]
```

Comment: Killer. Seems to do the job. Thank you!